# How can I avoid of executing a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a query like this:

```
 IF( @reputation < 50
     AND NEW.user_id != NEW.author_id
     AND (NEW.table_code != 15
          OR new.user_id != (SELECT
                                CASE WHEN a.related IS NULL THEN a.author_id 
                                     ELSE b.author_id END cols
                              FROM qanda a
                              LEFT JOIN qanda b ON a.related = b.id
                              WHERE a.id = NEW.post_id )
         )

   ) THEN
```

As you know that subquery *(`SELECT` statement)* will be executed first. I mean MySQL will execute the `SELECT` then evaluate the condition. Because that subquery *(`SELECT` statement)* is into parenthesis.

Well now I'm trying to avoid executing that subquery first. I want MySQL first of all evaluate all other conditions and then if all are `TRUE` then execute that subquery. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

how about this:

```
IF @reputation < 50
   AND NEW.user_id != NEW.author_id
THEN
    IF NEW.table_code != 15
       OR new.user_id !=
                         (
                          SELECT CASE
                                     WHEN a.related IS NULL
                                     THEN a.author_id
                                     ELSE b.author_id
                                 END cols
                          FROM qanda a
                          LEFT JOIN
                          qanda b
                          ON a.related = b.id
                          WHERE a.id = NEW.post_id
                         )
        THEN
```

Comment: Still that subquery is into a parenthesis and I think it will be executed first of all.

Comment: from what I understand the first IF statement will get executed then if that condition passes then the second

Comment: Wrong ..! No need to one more `IF` statement. The query in the question executes as expected. I mean the conditions run left-to-right in the `IF`-statement http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56f78/775